# Авторизация по голосу

Tags: java, android, авторизация

Как авторизовать пользователя по его голосу?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь этим: http://sourceforge.net/projects/marf/files/Applications/%5Bf%5D%20SpeakerIdentApp/0.3.0-devel-20060226/

Почитайте тут: http://marf.sourceforge.net/

Так же рекомендую глянуть эти сорцы: https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito

```
// Create a new Recognito instance defining the audio sample rate to be used
Recognito<String> recognito = new Recognito<>(16000.0f);

VoicePrint print = recognito.createVoicePrint("Elvis", new File("OldInterview.wav"));

// handle persistence the way you want, e.g.:
// myUser.setVocalPrint(print);
// userDao.saveOrUpdate(myUser);

// Now check if the King is back
List<MatchResult<String>> matches = recognito.identify(new File("SomeFatGuy.wav"));
MatchResult<String> match = matches.get(0);

if(match.getKey().equals("Elvis")) {
    System.out.println("Elvis is back !!! " + match.getLikelihoodRatio() + "% positive about it...");
}
```